# iPhone - view PDF like in iBooks

Tags: iphone, pdf

I have question about view for displaying multipage PDFs in my app. I have found solutions with webview but they lack ability to zoom and scroll between pages horizontally. Also found solutions using Quartz2D but the same problem as above.

Is there any way to present PDF like in iBooks? You can pinch-i/out zoom, list between pages horizontally. And also how to do taht with single PDF file, not split PDF to pages.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Maybe I am wrong but iOS4 should have pdf reading support. ?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: *04 Feb 2012*

Check out this project, it's opensource and very well made:

Project:
http://www.vfr.org/

Source:
https://github.com/vfr/Reader

Answer (score 2):

I can't give you the answer, but i can redirect you to a example project that is able to load and render a multipage pdf page by page.
To be honest this application it's manly on the iBook curl effect (forget it, it's a private API, no way) but inside there is a class that render on a view a pdf page, I'm sure that if you play a little with that code, `CGAffineTransformMakeScale`, `CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation` and touch control you will be able to obtain that effect.

Link to the project:
http://blog.steventroughtonsmith.com/2010/02/apples-ibooks-dynamic-page-curl.html

Comment: That page is interesting indeed, but i have found it about 5days ago :) I don`t intend to use page-curl effect. I only want view PDFs like iBooks app (not eBooks but PDFs - try it, it is displayed differently)

Answer (score 2):

Checkout this sample code from Apple:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/ZoomingPDFViewer/Introduction/Intro.html

It tells you how to efficiently display and zoom PDF documents.

For paging, see this link:

http://www.random-ideas.net/posts/42

Between the two of those you should be all set.

Comment: Don't try to use the approach of creating multiple CATiledLayers that ZoomingPDFViewer does. It doesn't work well. Use one CATiledLayer that can redraw.