# How could I create a solid, professional PDF book reader along the lines of iBooks?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, pdf, ibooks

Months ago I was intensly interested in this topic and construted a really crappy, horribly bogged down version of a pdf reader uising uiwebviews. However this obviously cannot be the best way to create a pdf view. All I could do was view the pdfs and each page had to be its own pdf.

Now here is my question: What kind of API's are available for creating great pdf readers. iBooks has the capability of changing font size, chapter indexes etc. I would really like this capability. I understand that Apple made iBooks however I'm hoping to construct something of equal or greater quality and would be happy to post the code online for everyone to see when I am done.

Thanks for the help in advance,

Nate

Comment: Why do you want to re-invent the wheel?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone - view PDF like in iBooks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099618/iphone-view-pdf-like-in-ibooks)

Comment: See also [PDF Reader like iBooks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187031/pdf-reader-like-ibooks) and [iPhone/iPad draw pdf like iBooks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810536/iphone-ipad-draw-pdf-like-ibooks).  As you can see, a lot of people want to replicate iBooks in some way: [http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%2Bibooks](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%2Bibooks)

Answer (score -1):

Nate,

iBooks doesn't actually do most of that stuff for PDFs, just for ePub books which have a very different structure. For PDFs you kind of limited in what you can do.

I'm not saying you can't make a nice product, but just that perhaps not they way you are hoping - at least for PDFs

Comment: This is not an answer and belongs in a comment.

Comment: Point taken - sorry about that.